# Confirmatory factor analysis parameterization of the 2-PL item response model

Tags: factor-analysis, latent-variable, confirmatory-factor, psychometrics, item-response-theory

For binary item response $i$ by person $j$, the 2-PL item response model is of the form:

$$Response_{ij} \sim Bernoulli(p_{ij})$$

$$logit(p_{ij}) \sim \alpha_i(\theta_j - \eta_i)$$

Usually, $\alpha_i$ is called a "discrimination" parameter affecting the scale of the item characteristic curves while $\eta_i$ is a "difficulty" parameter affecting the location of the item characteristic curve.

I've read that the 2-PL IRT model and the confirmatory factor analysis (CFA) models are equivalent, but I'm not sure how to write down the equivalent of a 2-PL item response model with a continuous outcome as a confirmatory factor analysis model when the Bernoulli distribution has one parameter while the Normal distribution used in CFA has two parameters.

In writing down a 2-PL-style item response model for a *continuous* outcome, do we treat the scale parameter of the normal distribution (the standard deviation) as the discrimination parameter and the mean of the distribution as a difficulty parameter? I would think it's something like the below, although I'm not sure about the indexing:

$$Response_{ij}  \sim Normal(\mu_{ji}, \sigma_{ij})$$
$$\mu_{ij} \sim Normal(\theta_j - \eta_i)$$
$$\sigma_{ij} \sim LogNormal(\kappa_{ij}, \sigma)$$